# Query string coming through get

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

Is it safe to query string coming through GET, as long as

- it itself isn't sensitive data
- I filter_input the GET string
- I mysqli_real_escape_string the string
- not relevant but I trim it too

I don't want any security issues.

Comment: Don't mysqli escape it..... if you're using mysqli, then use bind variables

Comment: Depends on what you’re actually doing with the data, because `mysqli_real_escape_string` is only supposed to be used for MySQL string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little difference between GET and POST as regards security. The main differences are:

- `GET` parameters will be visible in the location bar of the browser, unless you send a redirect
- The maximum size of `GET` parameters is very small, around 512 characters in PHP. `POST` parameters can be much larger.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't sending any sensitive data through a GET request there is nothing to worry about.